# Is every integral ring extension finite?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, extension-field

I think it is not necessarily the case. So far I have that if $S\subset R$ is a an integral infinite ring extension, we would need to have that $R$ is infinitely generated but $S[R]$ is finitely generated, both as S-modules.

Im having trouble coming up with a concrete example, though.

Comment: If $\;k\;$ is a finite field (to make the example easy) and $\;\overline k\;$ its algebraic closure, $\;\overline k/k\;$ is an algebraic extension of infinite degree.

Answer (score 4):

**Fact:** An $S$-Algebra $R$ is finite (i.e. finitely generated as an $S$-module) if and only if it is integral and of finite type (i.e. finitely generated as an $S$-algebra). [I guess you know this but I am not entirely sure whether I understood your notation correctly.]

**Hint** (for finding the desired example): Take a $S$-algebra $R$ that is *not* of finite type (and is reasonably easy to handle). Then "force" $R$ to be integral by modding out suitable relations while retaining the property of not being of finite type over $S$.

**Edit:** I guess the example provided by Timbuc in the comment to the original question is even simpler.

Comment: So for example $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra, not of finite type. It doesn't seem like I can mod anything out, though... Other than taking $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$, but thats still not integral

Comment: @Psy Yes, these are probably not the best choices to start with. Maybe you have better luck starting with something like a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables.

Comment: If I have $\mathbb{F}[x_1,x_2,...]$ the ring of polynomials in an infinite sequence of variables, this is an infinite $\mathbb{F}[x_2,x_3,...]$-module, but again the extension is not integral. The only thing I can think about for modding out would be $\mathbb{F}[x_1]$, but then of course you get the same thing..

Comment: I was thinking of $\mathbb{F}_2[x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}] / (x_n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N})$. This is integral, but not finite over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (why?). But I guess Timbuc's counterexample in the comment to your original question is even simpler.

Comment: @Psy In my example, $S = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $R = \mathbb{F}_2[x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}]/(x_n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb{N})$. I'm afraid the formulation of my hint might have caused the confusion, sorry.